# Access to MySql Database using Weka API

Tags: java, mysql, weka

I'm trying to use Weka API in a Java application and I'm getting some problems.

I can access MySql database changing RunWeka.ini last line:

```
cp=%CLASSPATH%;C:/Program Files/Weka-3-6/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
```

It works fine with Weka Explorer however I need to use Weka API in a java aplication I'm developing. I changed DatabaseUtils.props:

```
jdbcDriver=mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin
jdbcURL=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/DBNAME
```

My CLASSPATH var content is:

```
C:\Program Files\Weka-3-6\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25
```

When I try to run my Java App I get the next error and Weka Explorer database's connection doesn't work anymore.

```
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
```

Whan could be wrong? I know "DatabaseUtils.props" is being recognized because error's messages change.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the following line:

> jdbcDriver=mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin

It should have other value:

> jdbcDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: It was the solution I used. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

even the value provided in the original DatabaseUtils.props file works:

`jdbcDriver=org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver`

Comment: It was the solution I used. Thanks ;)